# What is the preferred way to organise and model svelte systems from an object oriented perspective?

Tags: svelte

I am working with Svelte to create an in-browser audio sampler. I typically work with object oriented (Ruby) code, so I tend to gravitate towards that approach when modelling systems. So in my system I have a `Group` class, and a `Sample` class. Groups manage the playback of samples and I want to indicate when a group is `active` i.e. it's playing a sample.

I have created a contrived example to demonstrate (see the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ac575d9a2a364aeb8a3dd586046ef88b?version=3.44.0)). The main App component looks something like:

```
<script>
  import Group from './group.js'
  import Sample from './sample.js'
  const groups = Array(4).fill().map((_, i) => new Group(i))

  const sample = new Sample([], groups[0])
</script>

{#each groups as group}
  <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={group.active} disabled />
{/each}

<button on:click={() => sample.play()}>
  Play
</button>
```

The four checkboxes represent groups, and should be checked once active. Pressing Play "plays" a Sample via Group 0, and activates that group. However due to its object oriented nature, this happens outside the component code, and therefore the UI is not reactive—so the checkbox does not update.

What is the preferred way to organise this code? (Given that I these models might be passed around various components etc)

Any pointers or advice to get me thinking in a more idiomatic Svelte way would be appreciated!

Comment: Made me think of [this example](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports), even if I'm not sure how many analogies there actually are it might be interesting in case you don't know it yet

Comment: Might as well not exactly reflect your example, but [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7d1ee5372df24fd9b3e5bc53550d67de?version=3.44.0) shows some ways how the play function could be invoked from different places when sitting inside a component structure

Comment: Thanks @Corrl! Your REPL example is neat. I wonder if there's a way to avoid duplicating the groups array? I wondering if I could model a Group as a custom store?

Comment: Customs stores are actually on top of my list of Svelte features to dig deeper into. Up to now I only use the 'default' ones... So I can't say for sure if/how to set up one in your case, but I think there is a good chance they might be useful (in any case :))

Comment: Cool! I think the thing that stuck in my head was this quotation from the tutorial: "It's very easy, therefore, to create custom stores with domain-specific logic." A Group encapsulates domain specific logic and so might be a good fit. For now, I've made the `active` property a store. Demonstrative answer to follow…

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Once potential approach is to move the checkboxes to a `GroupActive` component, and make the Group's `active` property a store:

```
// GroupActive.svelte
<script>
  export let id
  export let active
</script>

<input name="group_{id}_active" type="checkbox" bind:checked={$active} disabled />
```

---

```
// group.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export default class Group {
  constructor (id) {
    this.id = id
    this.active = writable(false)
  }

  play (buffer) {
    this.stop()
    this.source = this.createSource(buffer)
    this.source.start()
    this.active.set(true)
  }

  stop () {
    this.source?.stop()
    this.source = null
    this.active.set(false)
  }
  // …
}
```

The `active` store gets passed in via deconstruction, and so can be bound:

```
{#each groups as group}
  <GroupActive {...group} />
{/each}
```

Here's [a REPL to demonstrate this approach](https://svelte.dev/repl/b165e015d1254e32b2fb19760ae3780e?version=3.44.0)

Comment: Cannot help but notice that the `active` flag is redundant information, at least according to your `Group` class definition. You could move the group's `source` in a store and test if a source exists to determine if a group is active or not. In fact, typically, you'd want to have a store of groups, and manage your groups there (source, state, etc.) as whole entities. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I'd be interested to see what it would look like to manage a store of groups 